# X2go "qt_geo_map calling GLX 1.3 function "glXCreatePbuffer" when GLX 1.3 is not supported!"

Tags: linux, qt

This seems to be a X2go server issue, as described here

http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:de-compat

quote

```
Therefore, there are 4 reasons why certain modern “3d-ish” desktops are incompatible with nxagent, and therefore X2Go.
The desktop environment requires a newer version of the X11 extension “GLX” (OpenGL) than nxagent 3.5.0.x and X.org 6.9 provide (version 1.2).
```

I did some tests on

1. Ubuntu 16.04 Mint
2. CentOS 6.8

I tried both Qt for linux installations for Qt 5.8 and Qt 5.5.1

In CentOS 6.8  Qt 5.8 even fails to install

With Qt 5.5.1 in CentOS 6.8 and Qt 5.8 in Ubuntu 16.04 Mint I get this error trying to run the QtWebView minimal sample

```
failed to get the current screen resources
WARNING: Application /data/home002/pvicente/git/star_icvs/tools/build-qt_geo_map-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/qt_geo_map calling GLX 1.3 function "glXCreatePbuffer" when GLX 1.3 is not supported!  This is an application bug!
QSGContext::initialize: stencil buffer support missing, expect rendering errors
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 172 (Unknown), sequence: 163, resource id: 150, major code: 149 (Unknown), minor code: 20
```

*This seems to be a pure X2Go error *, since trying *ON THE LOCAL TERMINAL* (in Ubuntu 16.04 Mint with Qt 5.8, the program runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

as described here

https://github.com/QupZilla/qupzilla/issues/2084

this can be avoided by using

./my_QT_program --disable-gpu

under a X2Go session